# Maximize the probablity - tricky

Tags: probability

Gretel draws without replacement $n$ balls from the urn, which is $n$ white balls and $n$ black balls. White balls are numbered $1..n$, and black $n + 1, .. 2n$
We would like to Gretel to not draw balls, such that their number is $1$ or $2n$
That only thing we know is that she draw $b$ white balls and $n-b$ black.
Find such $b$ thatthe probability that Gretel didn't draw two special balls is greatest.

And my idea is following, but I don't know is it ok. Try to help me, please.

I will divide balls to four categories :
$Cat_1$ : white special ball (number one) was chosen
$Cat_2$ : $n-1$ white common balls were chosen
$Cat_3$ : $n-1$ black common balls were chosen
$Cat_4$ : black special ball (number $2n$) was chosen

$F_b$ - there were $b$ white balls chosen.
$F_{n-b} $ - there were $n-b$ black balls chosen.
$$P_r (F_b) = P_r(F_b|Cat_1)Pr(Cat_1) + P_r (F_b|Cat_2)Pr(Cat_2) $$
$$Pr(F_{n-b})=  P_r(F_{n-b}|Cat_3)Pr(Cat_3) + P_r (F_{n-b}|Cat_4)Pr(Cat_4) $$
So we search $Pr(Cat_4|F_{n-b}) + Pr(Cat_1|F_{b}) - Pr(Cat_4\cap Cat_1|  Pr(F_{n-b}\cap F_b) $
$$Pr(F_b | Cat_1) = \frac{{n-1\choose n-1}}{{2n-1\choose b-1}}$$
$$Pr(Cat_1) = \frac{1}{2n}$$
$$Pr(Cat_1|Fb) = \frac{Pr(F_b|Cat_1)Pr(Cat_1)}{Pr(F_b)} $$

Tell me, is it good way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation of "the probability that Gretel didn't draw two special balls" is that Gretel can draw one or the other or none, just not both.

---

I would not be casing on the categories. Since we are given the number of white and black balls drawn, I would case on that.

Given that we've drawn $b$ white balls out of $n$, the probability that the special white ball (ball $1$) is in those $b$ is $\frac{b}{n}$.

Given that we've drawn $n-b$ black balls out of $n$, the probability that the special black ball (ball $2n$) is in those $n-b$ is $\frac{n-b}{n}$.

We can also compute the probability that we haven't chosen the special ball.

Given that we've drawn $b$ white balls out of $n$, the number of ways not to draw the special white ball is $\binom{n-1}{b}$ out of $\binom{n}{b}$ ways to draw $b$ white balls.

Given that we've drawn $n-b$ black balls out of $n$, the number of ways not to draw the special black ball is $\binom{n-1}{n-b}$ out of $\binom{n}{n-b}$ ways to draw $n-b$ black balls.

---

**Second Approach**

Given that we've drawn $b$ white balls, the probability that a $1$ was not drawn is
$$
\frac{\binom{n-1}{b}}{\binom{n}{b}}=\frac{n-b}{n}
$$
and therefore, the probability that a $1$ was drawn is
$$
1-\frac{n-b}{n}=\color{#C00000}{\frac{b}{n}}
$$
Given that we've drawn $n-b$ black balls, the probability that a $2n$ was not drawn is
$$
\frac{\binom{n-1}{n-b}}{\binom{n}{b}}=\frac{b}{n}
$$
and therefore, the probability that a $2n$ was drawn is
$$
1-\frac{b}{n}=\color{#00A000}{\frac{n-b}{n}}
$$
Thus, the probability that we've drawn *both* a $1$ *and* a $2n$ is
$$
\color{#C00000}{\frac{b}{n}}\color{#00A000}{\frac{n-b}{n}}
$$
and therefore, the probability that we've avoided drawing *both* a $1$ *and* a $2n$ is
$$
1-\frac{b}{n}\frac{n-b}{n}
$$
Maximization with respect to $b$ is all that is left.

Comment: I don't agree with you. Firstly, Why these events are independent ?   Secondly " and therefore, the probability that we've avoided drawing both" - But we want to avoid both and only $1$ and only $2n$.  You try to simplify this task

Comment: Once we've decided how many of each we are choosing, the choice of white and black balls *is* independent. I had thought that we were tasked with avoiding both special balls, not either special ball. The question says that the event whose probability we want to maximize is "Gretel didn't draw two special balls".

Comment: Why these events are independent ?

Comment: Once we're given that we have $b$ white balls, and $n-b$ black balls, there is nothing in the choice of the black balls that will affect which white balls we choose.